# iterate through nested JSON

Tags: python, json, api

i'm trying to iterate in a json api respons and i'm unable to reach the data i need

here is a api response example. "i know it 's not complete or valid json :)"

```
{
"status": "running",
"reasons": [],
"nodes": {
    "Server1": {
        "status": "running",
```

and i'm using a simple for loop to iterate throught it !

```
for platforms in sbNode:
request = urllib2.Request(API URL)
json_res = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))
for node in json_res['nodes']:
    print node['status']
```

and i'm getting an error message

**TypeError: string indices must be integers**

and normaly i just print the for loop to see the json data but it just print Server1.

I'm lost here ....

Help !!!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_res['nodes']` is a dictionary. Iterating over a dictionary just gives you the keys, so the first value of `node` could be, for example, `'Server1'`. If you want both the keys and values you can iterate using `.items()`:

```
for key, node in json_res['nodes'].items():
```

If you only want the values of the nodes, you can use `.values()`:

```
for node in json_res['nodes'].values():
```

Comment: Here we go !! Thanks alot !!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a level of deepness of your data since `json_res['nodes']` is a dictionary

```
json_res['nodes'] = {
    "Server1": {
        "status": "running",
         ...
```

You can add a nested loop to print servers status:

```
for node in json_res['nodes']:
    for server in node:
         print server['status']
```